# Access denied when writing to a local path?

Tags: c#, webclient

After downloading from my FTP Server, and trying to overwrite that file with an updated one, I get an exception saying: "UnauthorizedAccessException was handled", that, Access to the Path 'C:\My Program\My Program\bin\Debug\App_Data' is denied.

This is what my code looks like:

```
private void downloadFile () {
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.Proxy = null;
    wc.Credentials  = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");

    byte[] fileData = wc.DownloadData("ftp://user:pass@mysite.tk/updates/App_Data/log.txt");
    File.WriteAllBytes(Application.StartupPath + "\\App_Data", fileData);   
}
```

Am I just missing something to set into the `WebClient` instance that can allow the 'File.WriteAllBytes' to write the file I'm downloading from my FTP Server to my local machine?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think about it, this obviously has nothing to do with `WebClient`. If you took the same sequence of bytes that you got from `WebClient`, and tried to write it to the same file, you'd get the same result.

In fact, you'd probably get the same result if you tried to write a single byte, and maybe zero bytes.

Like the exception says,

> Access to the Path 'C:\My Program\My Program\bin\Debug\App_Data' is denied

Does the `App_Data` folder even exist?

Comment: Yes. This is the path copied from my local machine: "C:\My Program\My Program\bin\Debug\App_Data" and this is the path that Intellisense is showing me: "C:\\My Program\\My Program\\bin\\Debug\\App_Data"

Comment: Then I guess you don't have write access. Simple as that.

Comment: Solved it. It had to include the file name after App_Data